# Adding Australian topographic base map WMTS to Leaflet web map

Tags: leaflet, wmts

I am trying to add [this topographic WMTS](https://ecat.ga.gov.au/geonetwork/srv/api/records/2b4ce65a-48cd-dcb7-e053-12a3070a632e) from Geoscience Australia as a base map to a Leaflet web map.

In QGIS I can create a new wmts connection and add the service using the connect point URL - https://services.ga.gov.au/gis/rest/services/Topographic_Base_Map/MapServer/WMTS/1.0.0/WMTSCapabilities.xml

[image]

Layer properties:

[image]

The service can also be seen in [ArcGIS online map viewer](https://www.arcgis.com/home/webmap/viewer.html?url=https%3A%2F%2Fservices.ga.gov.au%2Fgis%2Frest%2Fservices%2FTopographic_Base_Map%2FMapServer&source=sd), however I can not work out how to add this as a base map in my Leaflet web map.

I have looked at the [Leaflet Docs](https://leafletjs.com/examples/wms/wms.html) and tried to create a `L.tileLayer()`/ `L.tileLayer.wms()`

e.g.

```js
var topo_basemap = L.tileLayer('https://services.ga.gov.au/gis/rest/services/Topographic_Base_Map/MapServer/WMTS/1.0.0/Topographic_Base_Map/{z}/{x}/{y}.png').addTo(pMap);
```

and

```js
var topo_basemap = L.tileLayer.wms('https://services.ga.gov.au/gis/rest/services/Topographic_Base_Map/MapServer/WMTS',
{
format: 'image/png',
transparent: true,
layers: 'Topographic_Base_Map'
}).addTo(pMap);
```

The base map doesn't load. Inspecting the browser console, it seems like Leaflet is requesting tiles, but there are multiple `OpaqueResponseBlocking` warnings and I just don't know enough about this to start troubleshooting. I don't know if the problem is invalid/incorrect parameters in the `tileLayer()` constructor or something else.

[image]

How can I add this WMTS service as a basemap to my Leaflet web map?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The below three will work, but only up to and including zoom 12:

```
L.tileLayer('https://services.ga.gov.au/gis/rest/services/Topographic_Base_Map/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}');
L.tileLayer('https://services.ga.gov.au/gis/rest/services/Topographic_Base_Map/MapServer/WMTS/tile/1.0.0/Topographic_Base_Map/default/GoogleMapsCompatible/{z}/{y}/{x}.png');
L.tileLayer('https://services.ga.gov.au/gis/rest/services/Topographic_Base_Map/MapServer/WMTS/tile/1.0.0/Topographic_Base_Map/default/default028mm/{z}/{y}/{x}.png');
```

Despite capabilities document stating that zooms up to 23 are available, for zooms higher than 12 service returns status 400.